# Create new node in Godot editor that is a composition of multiple other nodes?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'd like to be able to define a component made of multiple nodes that I can reuse. Take for example the image below, where I have a custom Button node that has a Sprite2D as a child and a script that manages its behavior.

[image]

In this image, I have done the following steps manually **twice**:

- Add Button node, set its size and shape
- Add Sprite2D node, move it to the upper right corner
- Attach script to button

But this has many limitations:

- I'm going to be using this same setup multiple times in this project, and don't want to re-make it each time
- Usually I want to use the Godot scene editor, but it would be nice to at least be able to programmatically instantiate this
- When doing it manually, I may not position the Sprite2D in precisely the same location as other times, and I want it to be consistent

I tried registering the class as `DeleteMe` (this is an example) so I can add it as its own node, but then the child Sprite2D doesn't come with it.

```
class_name DeleteMe
extends Button
```

[image]

But as you can see, the Sprite2D child node didn't get added with it, neither did the shape, size, and text, that I set manually from the first two nodes.

I suspect this is a complete n00b question and I'm showing my ignorance by even asking it, but how do I define this `DeleteMe` component such that it will show up correctly in the Godot editor, and reproduce consistently?

I know I can define things programmatically in the code, perhaps by setting the text and creating the child node via `_init()` in GDScript, but I want the text and the child node to be visible when I use it **in the editor**.

And if I write the following in GDScript:

```
class_name DeleteMe
extends Button

func _init():
  text = "Example"
```

And *then* add it to the scene, I don't see "Example" as the button text!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do that in Godot.

The first one is the one you are trying right now. You start by declaring a script with the `class_name` keyword but then you need to create each component through code. Additionally, those changes should be made in the `_ready` method instead of `_init`, since `_init` is called way too early.

Something like this:

```
class_name DeleteMe
extends Button

func _ready():
  text = "Example"
  # Then you need to add the sprite as a child an set each property separately
  var sprite = Sprite2D.new()
  sprite.texture = preload('..path to texture')
  sprite.position = Vector2(0, 100)
  add_child(sprite)
```

`class_name` does not add the scene to the list of user defined classes, only the script. So any changes made to the scene would not be propagated to the new node.

However there is a better way to create reusable components in Godot.

Create a scene with only the button and the sprite. Then change any properties there.

Now you can use this component like this:

```
var DeleteMe = preload('...path to my component')
var deleteMe = DeleteMe.instantiate() # or .instance() if Godot 3
add_child(deleteMe)
```